# Prevent user to access login page if has logged in

Tags: php, authentication

I want to try create login page which it can be accessed by user if has not logged in, this is my code,

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['MM_Username']  != '') {
header ("Location: home.php");};
?>
```

It works!
But, it generates an error "Notice: Undefined index: MM_Username in C:\xampp\htdocs\msd\index.php".
What should I do now?

Comment: Using SESSION is only going to work if you've set it to a value earlier on. When your user logs in, do you set $_SESSION['MM_Username'] to include a value?

Comment: yes, of course. @kieran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the session exists or not using `isset`

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
header ("Location: home.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**check condition session start also for to prevent session already started notice.**

```
<?php
    if(!session_start()){
        session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
        header ("Location: home.php");
        }
    }
    ?>
```